# Multiple Objects Returned

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm beginner in python and Django rest And I stuck when I fetch data.

**Here is my API** :- http://127.0.0.1:8000/subjects/course/23/

I want a all subject data according to course which I select..When I hit this api if single data present working awesome but when inside course_id multiple subject present then gives me error such as :

**Exception Type:   MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value: get() returned more than one Subject -- it returned 2!**

Here is my model.py

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    course = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=False)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return "{}".format(self.title)
```

**Here is my serializer.py**

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:

        model = Subject
        fields = ('id', 'course', 'subject', 'description', 'amount', 'date_created', 'date_modified')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified')
        lookup_field = 'course'
```

**Here is my views.py**

```
class ViewSubjectAccordingCourse(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
"""This class handles the GET and POSt requests of our rest api."""
    queryset = Subject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubjectSerializer
    lookup_field = 'course'
```

**Here is my urls.py**

```
url(r'^subjects/course/(?P<course>[0-9]+)/$', ViewSubjectAccordingCourse.as_view(), name="details"),
```

Comment: Once course can have multiple subject, but your view is expecting one course per subject. So you have the wrong view type for what you are trying to display

Comment: I want to display a subject data according to course id .

Comment: That's great, but you don't filter anything; and you view is expecting one subject, when there are more than one subjects per course; hence your problem to start with.  You also don't have any relations between course and subject, your model is flat.

Comment: Ganesh, what @BurhanKhalid is saying is right, you need to fix your model. Maybe having a Foreign key from Course to Subject, allowing you to have N subjects link to a course.

Comment: I really don't know..how to give relation between them

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is

```
course = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=False)
```

this value is identical for more then one subject, as you send in unique=False this seems to be by design, is the plan to have one or more subjects per course?

If its meant to be many subjects, you need to use the `ListAPIView` and some `get_queryset` modifications. If course is ment to only have a single Subject then change the field to `unique=True`